# Nginx proxy_pass https to another nginx http

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Below is my nginx config file for my domain :

```
# This file is managed by gitlab-ctl. Manual changes will be
# erased! To change the contents below, edit /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
# and run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.

## GitLab
## Modified from https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/lib/support/nginx/gitlab-ssl & https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/lib/support/nginx/gitlab
##
## Lines starting with two hashes (##) are comments with information.
## Lines starting with one hash (#) are configuration parameters that can be uncommented.
##
##################################
##        CHUNKED TRANSFER      ##
##################################
##
## It is a known issue that Git-over-HTTP requires chunked transfer encoding [0]
## which is not supported by Nginx < 1.3.9 [1]. As a result, pushing a large object
## with Git (i.e. a single large file) can lead to a 411 error. In theory you can get
## around this by tweaking this configuration file and either:
## - installing an old version of Nginx with the chunkin module [2] compiled in, or
## - using a newer version of Nginx.
##
## At the time of writing we do not know if either of these theoretical solutions works.
## As a workaround users can use Git over SSH to push large files.
##
## [0] https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/Documentation/technical/http-protocol.txt#n99
## [1] https://github.com/agentzh/chunkin-nginx-module#status
## [2] https://github.com/agentzh/chunkin-nginx-module
##
###################################
##         configuration         ##
###################################

upstream gitlab-workhorse {
  server unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket;
}

## Redirects all HTTP traffic to the HTTPS host
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name example.com;
  server_tokens off; ## Don't show the nginx version number, a security best practice

  location / {
    return 301 https://domain:443$request_uri;
  }

  access_log  /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_error.log;
}

server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl http2;


  server_name example.com;
  server_tokens off; ## Don't show the nginx version number, a security best practice

  ## Increase this if you want to upload large attachments
  ## Or if you want to accept large git objects over http
  client_max_body_size 0;

  ## Strong SSL Security
  ## https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html & https://cipherli.st/
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

  # GitLab needs backwards compatible ciphers to retain compatibility with Java IDEs
  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4';
  ssl_protocols  TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout  5m;


  ## Real IP Module Config
  ## http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html

  ## HSTS Config
  ## https://www.nginx.com/blog/http-strict-transport-security-hsts-and-nginx/
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

  ## Individual nginx logs for this GitLab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  if ($http_host = "") {
    set $http_host_with_default "example.com";
  }

  if ($http_host != "") {
    set $http_host_with_default $http_host;
  }

  ## If you use HTTPS make sure you disable gzip compression
  ## to be safe against BREACH attack.
  gzip off;

  ## https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
  ## Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
  proxy_read_timeout      3600;
  proxy_connect_timeout   300;
  proxy_redirect          off;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;

  proxy_set_header Host $http_host_with_default;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;

  location ~ /gitlab/(\.git/gitlab-lfs/objects|\.git/info/lfs/objects/batch$) {
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_pass http://gitlab-workhorse;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
  }

  location /gitlab/ {
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_pass  http://gitlab-workhorse;
  }

  location /gitlab/assets/ {
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_pass  http://gitlab-workhorse;
  }

  error_page 404 /gitlab/404.html;
  error_page 422 /gitlab/422.html;
  error_page 500 /gitlab/500.html;
  error_page 502 /gitlab/502.html;
  location ~ ^/gitlab/(404|422|500|502)(-custom)?\.html$ {
    root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;
    internal;
  }

  ## PERSONAL CHANGE ######################################################################################################################

  location / {
    # return 301        https://example.com:443/gitlab;
    proxy_pass  https://example.com/gitlab/;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }

  location /beta {
    proxy_pass  http://example.com:8080;
    resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off;
  }

}
```

As you can read I used the original gitlab's nginx's file and it works well. I have only one server because I can't have subdomains. So to separate websites I use "example.com/website" here example.com/gitlab and example.com/beta .
However the website "beta" is actually inside a VM on the same server, we used to access it by the port :8080. But since it doesn't have SSL, browsers don't like it.
So I figure out why not proxy_pass this website on my main server but I get a 502 error Bad Gateway when I try to reach https://example.com/beta (please note that the website 'beta' is HTTP only). This website is a Django one, I don't know if it has any impact.
I don't really know why it doesn't work with this configuration.

At the moment :

- http://example.com/* -> https://example.com/*
- https://example.com/gitlab -> website gitlab
- https://example.com/* -> https://example.com/gitlab
- https://example.com/beta -> error 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: Have you checked both nginx error logs?

Comment: The nginx error shows only that nginx tries to connect to my domain by IPv6 (that's why I did resolver ipv6=off) but it doesn't change anything